# Snapshot incorrect in release mode, works correctly in debug mode

Tags: c++, windows, file, file-io, snapshot

I have program to take snapshots of all volume in a disk. It will read the data in each volume using the `FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP`. It writes the data to another file.

Everything works fine, but it doesn't when I change the code as indicated:

If the volume contains OS then I will copy some driver files into system32/drivers, so a write has occured before I read the data.

I read the Volumebitmap that is obtained using `FSCTL_GET_VOLUME_BITMAP` after the write completion only. But it returns values of the newly copied files only. All other data which were already present are 0.

When I tried to debug the code in debug mode it takes perfectly the old data + new data.
But when I try to run in Release mode it gives the changed value that is the newly copied files only.

What would be the problem that makes this in debug and release mode?

I tried to set the property C/C++  Optimization, Whole program Optimization -> Yes, then it provides the wrong value. But if I set it to "No" then it provides correct result.

So the problem occurs during the Release mode.

Comment: This question is flying under the radar. It does not contain any tags that are commonly used. With the amount of stackoverflow questions, it is gone from the front page in 3..2..1..

Comment: Make sure you don't have any "functional" code inside of an assert(). They get stripped out in release mode.